# How to show a real matrix $A$ belongs to Indefinite Orthogonal Group $O(n;k)$?

Tags: lie-groups, bilinear-form

I want to show that an $(n + k) \times (n + k)$ real matrix $A$ belongs to $O(n;k)$ iff $gA^Tg = A^{-1}$. I know that for all $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, and for the matrix 
$$ 
g = \begin{pmatrix}
I_n & 0 \\
0 & -I_k \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

if $[\cdot,\cdot]_{n,k}$ is the bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ defined as $$[\vec{x},\vec{y}]_{n,k} = x_1y_1 + \cdots x_ny_n - x_{n+1}y_{n+1} - \cdots - x_{n+k}y_{n+k},$$

it is true that $[\vec{x},\vec{y}]_{n,k} = \langle \vec{x}, g\vec{y} \rangle$. I know I want to show $[A\vec{x},A\vec{y}]_{n,k} = [\vec{x},\vec{y}]$. So, my first thinking is to consider $[A\vec{x},A\vec{y}]_{n,k} = \langle A\vec{x}, gA\vec{y} \rangle$ and somehow cleverly multiply by the identity $gA^TgA = I$.

However, I am sooo lost on doing so. Help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$\langle Ax,gAy\rangle =\langle x,A^TgAy\rangle$. $A^TgA=g^{-1}$ you deduce that $\langle Ax,Ay\rangle=\langle x,g^{-1}y\rangle=\langle x,gy\rangle$ since $g=g^{-1}$.

Comment: How does $\langle Ax, gAy \rangle = \langle x, A^TgAy \rangle$? Specifically, how does the $Ax$ -> $x$?

Comment: If $A$ is any matrix $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^Ty\rangle$.

Comment: Got it. Proved this fact a bit later and helped me go back to the original question, THANKS!